# How to use all 4 CPU cores for performing operation using Executor Framework?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to perform fetch logs operation from a remote Splunk server. My CPU has 4 cores. I am using Executor Framework with CorePoolSize as 4. But, only 1 thread is working on fetching the logs. What should I do so that 4 threads work concurrently?

Code:

```java
public Executor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor= new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProecssors());
    executor.setMaxPoolSIze(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Is this java? How are you executing the tasks? Is the task itself synchronized? How do you know only 1 thread is working?

Comment: Yes, its Java. I have used CompletableFuture for Async operation. In eclipse console i could see only one thread being used.

Comment: You'll need to include the code for starting/submitting your tasks.

Comment: It is actually a SpringBoot application. I have used @EnableAsync. I was wonderig if i am configuring my threadpool correctly or not for my CPU whch has 4 cores.

Comment: Did you check what "availableProcessors()" is returning?

Comment: it is returning 4.

Comment: in controller i am using: CompletableFuture<List<String>> result1= myService.MyFetcherAPI(searchString); result1.get();

Comment: You're still missing code. You can edit your question to include the code, such as the code from your comment on the other comment AND how you're setting up your executor as being the executor for the service/controller. If I am not mistaken, if you want your service to actually use this executor you need to add an annotation to your method?

Comment: which method level annotation should i use in Service. i have used @Async

Comment: You can google exactly that, and find some resources. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Answer (score -1):

You said about fetching logs, maybe you can't open the same file concurrently and/or make operation on it.

Comment: There is no issue with fetching logs concurrently. My issue is if my threadpool config is correct for using 4 cpu cores so that i can use 4 threads.

Comment: in controller i am using:    CompletableFuture<List<String>> result1= myService.MyFetcherAPI(searchString);CompletableFuture<List<String>> result2= myService.MyFetcherAPI(searchString); CompletableFuture.allOf(result1,result2).join()